# gitolite hooks - post-receive doesn't seem to work

Tags: git, hook, gitolite, mailnotifier

I have gitolite configured on my repo.  I see 2 copies of the hooks as documented in the gitolite literature.  I would like the server-side hook post-receive to send email when someone does a push to the repo.
I am using git-notifier.  However, nothing happens when I push.  I have modified both copies of the hooks, and I added a line to create a tmp file.  After I push my changes to the repo, no tmp file is there and no email is sent.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: As the gitolite user, verify that the hook is present and executable in the repositories in question. Instead of a temp file, simply echo output - it will be forwarded back to the pushing client. (And make sure to do it at the very very top.)

Comment: I've added the `git` tag to your question - I never saw it until you posted your not-a-question rant today, since it wasn't properly tagged. I think if you take the time to ask clear questions, and have a little bit of patience, you'll find that SO can be a great help to you - though of course, no replacement for reading manpages, using google, and trying things on your own.

Comment: Thanks Jefromi.  I have tried all of your suggestions to get help.

Comment: I changed my touch command to echo "inside post.receive hook". I modified a file on master, committed it and pushed it to the origin/repo.  I also verified that the hooks are present in the repository and executable.  Still no luck.

Comment: anyone else care to take a stab at helping me please???? :-)

Comment: accidently came across the cause of my problem. I have sym links to /usr/local/share copies of the gitolite hooks(this was setup by default).  I changed the sym links to point to /home/git/.gitolite/hooks/common/*, and the hooks started firing.  I figured this out because a branch new repo had the sym links pointing here.  All of my other repos existed when I migrated from gitosis to gitolite.  Perhaps the migration doc or script needs to be changed to reflect this?

Comment: You should post this as an answer to your question and except it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should run the following commands:

```
gitolite/src/gl-system-install
gl-setup
```

The only place you have to modify the hooks is on `gitolite/hooks/common`. The above commands takes care of updating the hooks in all repositories.