# How to install hooks in gitolite

Tags: git, githooks, gitolite

I've read all [the documentation about hooks](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/2-admin.mkd#_using_hooks), [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055190/how-to-setup-post-receive-email-git-hook-with-gitolite) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937755/gitolite-hooks-post-receive-doesnt-seem-to-work) and [a lot of code](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/src/gl-install#L91) but I can't track where is the error in my procedure. I need to install a simple hook in my gitolite installation (made with an rpm package on CentOS) so here is what I did:

To install gitolite (some time ago):

1. Installed the rpm package
2. `# su - gitolite`
3. `$ gl-setup /tmp/fabio.pub` (as gitolite user)

Now to install the hook:

1. Created a sample file `post-update` with the hook code in `~gitolite/.gitolite/hooks/common` and `chmod +x` on it
2. run `gl-setup /tmp/fabio.pub` again as [stated here](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/2-admin.mkd#_using_hooks)

But nothing happened, the exit status from the latest command is 0, but the hook file is not symlinked in any of the repository. So what's wrong with my procedure? Have I missed something?

Bonus questions:

1. If I had understood the doc my procedure is the right one? I.e. should I run gl-setup every time I update any hook?
2. In this way I install the shared hooks in every repository under this gitolite installation, is that right? Can I manually install an hook either as symlink to somewhere or just an executable script only for a given repository? Should I do that manually in the hook folder of the given repository? Should I care of hooks conflicts (i.e. would any custom hook for the single repository block any other shared hook with the same name)?

Don't know if this matters, my gitolite version is `1.5.9.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that if I copy my hook sample in `/usr/share/gitolite/hooks/common/` it will be symlinked by `gl-setup`. Maybe in this package `$GL_ADMINDIR` variable is not set for some reason. Two bonus questions still stands...

Answer (score 1):

In Gitolite v3 you may choose where to put your hooks editing `LOCAL_CODE` variable in `.gitolite.rc`. See the file source for more options (eg. enabling per repo custom hooks)

Then you put your hooks in the specified dir, make them executable and run `gitolite setup --hooks-only`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an `update.secondary` hook in the directory then redeploy with gl-easyinstall.  Take a look at the update hook that comes with gitolite. You will see that near the end, it calls `update.secondary`. If you provide that, it will work.

Comment: I don't need an update hook, so I don't think this would solve my issue. Plus I've installed from a package, so I think my command is not `gl-easyinstall` but `gl-setup`.

Comment: you update hooks in the gitolite clone and then re-run the easy install script. What is the objective of your hook? Most things are done through the update hook.

Comment: [this is the hook I need](https://github.com/kahseng/redmine_gitolite_hook/blob/master/contrib/hooks/post-receive-redmine_gitolite). I simply can't run `gl-easyinstall` because I don't have a local clone since I've installed gitolite using the [package method](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/1-INSTALL.mkd#_package_method).

Comment: I'd reinstall from client. Your script can be adjusted to be an update script. Instead of stdin, your old, new and refspec are going to come as command line args. Easy change. You'll have an easier time updating hooks if you install from the client side.