# Per-branch, per-repo commit hook in gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite, githooks, git-post-receive

I want to add a commit hook that works when a push is received on a gitolite/git server for a given branch and repo combination only (branch 'cat' on repo 'dog').

My environment:
git version 1.7.4.1,

What I have done so far:

1. Touched a file at `/home/git/repositories/dog.git/hooks/post-receive.secondary` on the git/gitolite server.
2. Edited the file with the contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   #
   refname="$1"
   oldrev="$2"
   newrev="$3"
   if [ "$refname" == "refs/heads/cat" ]
   then
      touch /tmp/test
   fi
   ```
3. Set the owner of the file to the 'git' user
4. Set the file permissions to 700
5. Done a commit to "cat" branch of "dog" repo

Results:
the test file is not created

Comment: If you add an echo in your script, is it displayed? And do you have gitolite v2 or v3?

Comment: @VonC - from the src/CHANGELOG I believe I am running v2.0 but I can't find a binary to execute to verify this. I will check the echo command in the script and respond shortly

Comment: Simple: if you have '`gl-xxx`' commands in your gitolite, this is V2.

Comment: @VonC -  they are not in my PATH but there are gl-xxx commands in /home/git/.gitolite/src, yes

Comment: and if I run the script manually, passing in the refname then yes it executes fine, it is simply not getting executed, or failing somehow when I commit code to that branch on that repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I look at [Gitolite v2 (g2) hook chaining section](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/hooks.html#hookchaining), only two hooks are concerned with the "`.secondary`" extension:

- The update hook, because it is used in all repos and is critical to gitolite's access control
- The post-update hook, because it is used in the `gitolite-admin` repo only, to "compile" the configuration and so on.
- (`post-receive` is only involved if mirroring is activated, which shouldn't be the case in your gitolite installation)

So you shouldn't need to declare a `post-receive.secondary`, just a `post-receive` hook in your `</path/to/gitolite>/hooks/common/`, as described in "[How to install hooks in gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617926/6309)".

---

The [OP specialsauce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1459145/specialsauce)  concludes in the comments:

> I needed a `post-receive` hook in the repository folder (Rather than a secondary one) , which I think was the main reason that it wasn't executing.
>
> The only other thing I changed in the end I believe was setting the perms from `700` (which should have been fine anyway?) to `755`.
>   The hook now executes reliably.
>
> I did not need to run the `gl-setup` script. Additionally I changed from the var assignment code as outlined above to a "while" on `STDIN`.

Comment: there is a `post-receive.mirrorpush` symlink, which is why I used the `.secondary` filename. With regard to putting the hook in `</path/to/gitolite>/hooks/common/`, I explicitly wanted this hook only to take effect for commits to a single repository, whereas I beleive hooks in the common location would trigger on a commit to any repository

Comment: @user1459145 no, you should use a .secondary because of a `post-receive.mirrorpush`: the doc is clear: "Shipped as `post-receive.mirrorpush`, it is renamed to '`post-receive`' and installed as part of the mirroring setup": if you don't see a  '`post-receive`', you can create your own.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. However, I have moved the file to `post-receive` and run a second commit, and still see no temp file created.

Comment: @user1459145 did you put an echo in that script, just to see if it was at least called? Did you first symlink your script to all repo by running `gl-setup` again?

Comment: thanks for your perseverance. the echo is in that script, yes. So the script's correct home is `</path/to/gitolite>/hooks/common/post-receive`, and it will only actually execute for a given repository if that repo has the symlink from `</path/to/repository>/hooks/post-receive` to `</path/to/gitolite>/hooks/common/post-receive` ?

Comment: @user1459145 yes, the symlink needs to be in place, which `gl-setup` should do automatically for you.

Comment: I manually relocated the file and set up the symlink as above, and this still did not work. I am loathe to reconfigure using gl-setup after reading the documentation for it since it doesn't look ever to have been run on this host and I do not want to break any existing configuration.

Comment: @user1459145 interesting: a gitolite without gl-setup. I am not sure how it can work. I would recommend setting up in a different path a gitolite V3 (a simple clone will be enough, followed by a `gitolite setup`, like I did in https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitolite/install_or_update_gitolite.sh)

Comment: thank you for your assistance and persistence, this problem is now resolved.

Comment: @specialsauce: excellent. Do you have any details on the specifics of the resolution? I will edit my answer and add them, for other readers to benefit from.

Comment: your basic answer was correct, that I needed a post-receive hook in the repository folder (Rather than a secondary one) which I think was the main reason that it wasn't executing. The only other thing I changed in the end I beleive was setting the perms from 700 (which should have been fine anyway?) to 755. The hook now executes reliably. I did not need to run the gl-setup script. Additionally I changed from the var assignment code as outlined above to a "while" on STDIN. I'm not 100% sure which of these changes resolved the issue.

Comment: @specialsauce: understood. I have edited the answer to include your conclusions, for more visibility.